# Time of program at different moments

Tags: c#, windows, algorithm, time

I have just finished a project, but i 've got a question from my teacher. Why does my program (with  same algorithm, same data, same environment) run with different finish time at different moments.?
Can anyone help me?

Example: Now my program runs for 1.03s.
but then it runs for 1.05s (sometimes faster 1.01).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea here but could it be because of the changes on the memory usage, cpu usage by the background applications changes on different times. I mean time difference would create difference only on;

- The memory usage by the other applications
- The physical conditions such as cpu heat. ( The changes in time is really small )
- And system clock. If you do a random number generation or do any operation that uses system clock on the background might create that change.

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because your program is not the only entity executing in the system and it does not get all the resources immediately at all times.

For this reason it's practically of little value to measure short execution times as they are going to vary quite noticeably. Instead, if you're interested in more accurate time measurements, you should execute your code many times and calculate the average time of all runs.

Answer (score 1):

Because Windows is not a real time operating system. Many other activity can happen when your program is executed, and the cpu can share its cycles with other running processes. Time can change even more if your program need to read from physical devices as disk ( database too ) and the net: this because physical resource can be busy serving other requests. memory could change things too, if there is `page faults`, so your app need to read pages from virtual memory and as a result you will see a performance decrease. Since you are using C#, time can change sensibly from first execution to the others in the same process, due to the fact the code is `JITtted`, ie is compiled from intermediate code to assembly the first time is seen, then it is used in the assembly form, that is dramatically faster.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy. You capture system time difference, using a counter that's imprecise as it uses system resources. There are more programs that run in parallel with yours, some take priority over your code causing temporary (~20ms, depending on OS settings) suspension of your thread. Even in DOS there is code that runs in quasi-parallel with yours, given there's only one thread possible, your code is stalled while the time is still ticking (it's governed by that code).

Comment: There's a lot of answers here, pick one that suits you best and accept it via "tick" on the left of the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is wrong. The environment does not stay the same. The available resources for your program depend on many things. E.g. CPU and memory utilization by other processes, e.g. background processes. The harddisk and/or network utilization due to other processes. Even if there are no other processes running your program will change the internal state of the caches.

In "real world" performance scenarios it is not uncommon to see fluctuations of +/- 20% after "warm up". That is: measure 10 times in a row as "warm up" and discard the results. Measure 10 times more and collect the results. --> +/- 20% is quite common. If you do not warm up you might even see differences several orders of magnitude due to "cold" caches.

Conclusion: your program is very small and uses very little resources and it does not benefit from durable cache mechanisms.